# Why every element I create gets deleted istantly?

Tags: reactjs, function, state, call

I am making a Contact Manager(I already did it with App as a class component and now I am doing it with App as a functional component) and every time I create an element, it gets deleted instantly because the removeElement function is called instantly...Can someone tell me why?

P.S. Sorry for my terrible English...

[this](https://pastebin.com/wPmxNGZB) is the link of the code

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [people, setPeople] = React.useState([]);
  const [person, setPerson] = React.useState({
    name: "",
    age: "",
    email: ""
  });

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setPerson({ ...person, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    if (person.name && person.age && person.email) {
      const newPerson = { ...person, id: new Date().getTime().toString() };
      setPeople([...people, newPerson]);
      setPerson({ name: "", age: "", email: "" });
    }
  };

  const removeItem = (id) => {
    setPeople(people.filter((person) => person.id !== id));
  };

  const clearList = () => {
    setPeople([]);
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h1>React Contact Manager</h1>

      <div className="inputs">
        <input
          type="text"
          name="name"
          value={person.name}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />

        <input
          type="number"
          name="age"
          value={person.age}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />

        <input
          type="mail"
          name="email"
          value={person.email}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
      </div>

      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Add</button>

      <ul className="result">
        {people.map((person) => (
          <li key={person.id}>
            <h4>{person.name}</h4>
            <h6>{person.age}</h6>
            <span>{person.email}</span>
            <button onClick={removeItem(person.id)}>Remove</button>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>

      <div className="clear">
        <button onClick={clearList}>Clear</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Item is deleted because you are executing this function - `removeItem(person.id)` - on every render.

Change:

```
<button onClick={removeItem(person.id)}>Remove</button>
```

to:

```
<button onClick={() => removeItem(person.id)}>Remove</button>
```

Or create a function and assign it to the button:

```
const removePerson = () => {
   removeItem(person.id);
}
<button onClick={removePerson}>Remove</button>
```